# AS3 AIR RequestSoftKeyboard not working on Windows

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I tried to launch a virtual keyboard on Windows using this:

```
_txtInputName = new TextField();
_txtInputName.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
_txtInputName.needsSoftKeyboard = true;
_txtInputName.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, onFocus );

private function onFocus(e:FocusEvent):void
{
    _txtInputName.requestSoftKeyboard();
}
```

Unfortunaly, the softkeyboard doesn't show up. Am I missing something? Does I have to add something on the application.xml?

Thank you so much!

Comment: My understanding is there is no soft keyboard for non-mobile platforms as it is provided by the mobile OS thus Windows and OS-X do not show one within the context of the Air application. You would need open the desktop OS provided virtual on-screen keyboard.

Comment: You mean ask the user to open it manually? If so, are there some libraries that would add some custom virtual keyboard?

Comment: I do not know of another way unless you write an ANE that handles the  'text automation peer' via TextAutomationPeer/AutomationPeer, least that is how you do it in Windows 8+... But I'm unsure of if that would even work within an Air ANE....

Comment: There are a couple of virtual keyboards for ActionScipt/Flex floating around, I personally have not used them: https://github.com/GrfxGuru/Adobe-Flex-4.5-Components & http://quetwo.com/2010/11/28/virtual-keyboard/ , etc..

Comment: Assuming you are creating some type of kiosk fullscreen app that does not have a physical keyboard attached?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am creating. Using the softKeyboard on Android/iOS worked well (with StageText) but it doesn't in WIndows.

Comment: I did one a 'while' back and originally the client wanted it to be Windows PC based, but due to things like the soft keyboard, cost of Windows touch screens, the PC itself, etc.. I finally talked them out of it by showing them an Android based prototype and we ordered a bunch of cheap large screen 'drioid tablets from China for a fiction of the cost of doing it on a PC.... good luck on your project

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll go with a custom virtual keyboard then!

Answer (score 1):

TextField is not an object type compatible with native keyboard handling. As a coder using a TextField does mean not using native keyboard at all. SO simple answer to your question is this:

Of course it's not working since it's not mean to.

Next: To provide native keyboard support on the AIR platform the StageText built-in class was implemented and is the one any coder wanting to handle native keyboard should use.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html