# Show virtual on screen keyboard in Adobe Air application on Touch-Monitor

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air, touch

I am developing an app with adobe air (v20) on FDT with AS3. I have to include an input textfield on a touh monitor. But I didn't make it happen to pop up the virtual keyboard. I have tried "needsSoftKeyboard" and "requestSoftKeyboard". But nothing worked.

any suggestions?

Comment: **(1)** See if the comments in this other [**Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33186093/2057709) can help you. **(2)** Try opening the On-Screen Keyboard by using `nativeProcess` API (point to :  _c:/windows/system32/osk.exe_). For this, whenever you get a textfield's focus event, have a boolean (check if k/board is already open or else load via nativeProcess), then close/end the process when focus is removed...

Comment: Thx @VC.One ... I tried opening the keyboard by using a nativeProcess but it didn't worked. I debugged the file `new File("c:\\windows\\system32\\osk.exe")` which tells me that it exists, but nothing happened if I call the start() method of the nativeProcess.


`var nativeProcessStartupInfo : NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();

var file : File = new File("c:\\windows\\system32\\osk.exe");

nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;

process = new NativeProcess();

process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);`

Comment: Ok, I made it ... It's working. But now I have the problem, to close the keyboard on focus out of the textfield. I tried `taskkill /T /F /IM TabTip.exe` via cmd-tool request, but it didn't worked. I think it is not working because of the missing admin rights. I can't find out, how to solve this problem.